# Milnor's definition of bundle map in "Characteristic Classes"

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

In chapter 3 of "Characteristic Classes", Milnor defines bundle maps, requiring them to map fibers isomorphically onto fibers.  Why not merely require homorphisms on fibers? (e.g., for the given definition, the inclusion map of a subbundle doesn't qualify as a bundle map.)  Is it a matter of convenience, or is there something else going on?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is just for convenience. Certainly you can define more general notions of bundle map. However, you might want to be careful with taking fiberwise kernels or cokernels, since that can take you out of the world of vector bundles (and into the more general world of *sheaves*). A simple example is the map from the trivial rank-1 bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ to itself that over $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is given by multiplication by $t$. To avoid this sort of thing, you can demand that a bundle map have locally constant rank.

Answer (score 4):

One can define characteristic classes in a more general context. For any topological group $G$, there is a universal [principal $G$-bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle) (henceforth just $G$-bundle) $EG \to BG$. $BG$ is called the classifying space of $G$, because isomorphism classes of principle $G$-bundles over $X$ correspond bijectively to homotopy classes of maps $f: X \to BG$, the correspondence taking a representative map, and defining the pullback bundle $f^*(EG \to BG)$, a $G$-bundle on $X$. (This turns out to depend only on the homotopy class of $f$.)

Now, pick an $\alpha \in H^*(BG;A)$ for some commutative ring $A$. We define the "$\alpha$-characteristic class" (this is not standard terminology - I just made it up) for a $G$-bundle $E \to X$ to be the class $f^*\alpha \in H^*(X;A)$, where $f: X \to BG$ is the defining map for our $G$-bundle. Then if $g: Y \to X$ is a continuous map, the $\alpha$-characteristic class of the pullback bundle $g^*(E \to X)$ is precisely $g^*(f^*(\alpha))$. You might notice this is the way Milnor's characteristic classes transform...

Indeed, to any real $n$-dimensional vector bundle, there is a canonically assigned $O(n)$-bundle (and this correspondence is again bijective on isomorphism classes). One may calculate (indeed, Milnor-Stasheff do) that $H^*(BO(n),\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z_2[w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n]$, a polynomial algebra with $|w_i| = i$. For any real, $n$-dimensional vector bundle $E \to X$, let $f$ be the representing map $X \to BO(n)$; then $w_i(E) = f^*(w_i)$. One may do something analagous for complex vector bundles ($\cong$ $U(n)$-bundles); this gives Chern classes.

Now, what Milnor and Stasheff call a bundle map $E \to E'$, where $E \to X$ is a vector bundle and so is $E' \to Y$, is precisely the same as a map $f: X \to Y$ such that $f^*(E') = E$. So the above discussion makes it clear this is how characteristic classes transform: under pullback maps, because that's precisely how we get a map $H^*(Y;A) \to H^*(X;A)$ in cohomology!

Indeed, if you tried to define how characteristic classes transform by some '$f^*$' under your sort of bundle map, we no longer have the formula $f^*(w_i(E')) = w_i(E)$; for take $E$ to be the trivial 0-dimensional bundle over the 1-point space, and $E'$ to be literally any vector bundle; the formula would say that $w_i(E') = 0$ for all $E'$. If you try to weaken your hypotheses a little bit (maybe only homomorphisms between $n$-dimensional vector bundles?) you get the same problem.